# experiencing super slow tests with testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm currently experimenting testcafe for the first time, I use the [testdriven.io](http://testdriven.io/) course as an example, and I'm facing really slow tests.

For instance `testcafe e2e/login.test.js` which is basically a register and a login takes sometimes 6min to pass, which I found insanely slow compared to the 15s the author has in his course.

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

const randomstring = require('randomstring');
const username = randomstring.generate();
const email = `${username}@test.com`;
const TEST_URL = process.env.TEST_URL;
fixture('/login').page(`${TEST_URL}/login`);


test(`should display the sign-in form`, async (t) => {
    await t
        .navigateTo(`${TEST_URL}/login`)
        .expect(Selector('H1').withText('Login').exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('form').exists).ok()
});

test(`should allow a user to sign in`, async (t) => {
// register user
    await t
        .navigateTo(`${TEST_URL}/register`)
        .typeText('input[name="username"]', username)
        .typeText('input[name="email"]', email)
        .typeText('input[name="password"]', 'test')
        .click(Selector('input[type="submit"]'))
// log a user out
    await t
        .click(Selector('a').withText('Log Out'))
// log a user in
    await t
        .navigateTo(`${TEST_URL}/login`)
        .typeText('input[name="email"]', email)
        .typeText('input[name="password"]', 'test')
        .click(Selector('input[type="submit"]'))
// assert user is redirected to '/'
// assert '/' is displayed properly
    const tableRow = Selector('td').withText(username).parent();
    await t
        .expect(Selector('H1').withText('All Users').exists).ok()
        .expect(tableRow.child().withText(username).exists).ok()
        .expect(tableRow.child().withText(email).exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('User Status').exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Log Out').exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Register').exists).notOk()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Log In').exists).notOk()
// log a user out
    await t
        .click(Selector('a').withText('Log Out'))
// assert '/logout' is displayed properly
    await t
        .expect(Selector('p').withText('You are now logged out').exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('User Status').exists).notOk()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Log Out').exists).notOk()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Register').exists).ok()
        .expect(Selector('a').withText('Log In').exists).ok()
});
```

I tried with Firefox, same deal, albeit much faster, 44s.

```
(project-tOIAx_A8) ➜  testdriven-app git:(master) ✗ testcafe 'chromium' e2e/login.test.js        
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
(node:16048) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 67.0.3396 / Linux 0.0.0

 /login
 ✓ should display the sign in form
 ✓ should allow a user to sign in


 2 passed (6m 15s)
```

I wish I could provide more info, went to the dev tools, inspected the console without noticing any error message except this one sometimes:

```
hammerhead.js:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.195:38039/4wxhbvTF7!w!http%3A%2F%2F172.18.0.5/http://172.18.0.5/sockjs-node/444/2kjm15kn/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

, the waterfall looks like slow, is there a way to give a log report of it to help understand what cases this slowness ?

edit: I put a .debug() at beginning and at the end of the tests and save a [Performance profile inside Firefox](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/euri10/65cff03cf91769267f41725c9c2f0e02/raw/0e47d353e5d24b17e932e11cc8a155a0c83cb6f4/profile.json) if that helps

edit2: this is a [performance profile in chromium](https://gist.github.com/euri10/05b6b52b48ba66df4dbdcbd7e6b68c1e) if that helps

[image]

Comment: According to your Chrome log, XHR requests fall off on a timeout. From what I gather, your server can be run locally or on Amazon. In the first case, you can define the "--hostname localhost" argument and use "localhost" as a test URL. In the case of Amazon, try a local server and VPN to check how tests run via VPN.

Comment: my app runs in docker containers, I export TEST_URL before running testcafe, it points to my nginx container which serves a React app, could that be the root of the issue ?

Comment: Would you please upload your container(-s) to Docker Hub so that I will check it locally or share some parts of your code? In addition, clarify which OS you are using and provide the "docker-machine ls" command output.